# Jquery autocomplete apply paging on data

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

in my jquery autocomplete i have integrated an ajax call that fetches me data by size of page and index of page like (if i want to show 5 results i pass pageindex=1, and pagesize=5) and if for next 5 records i pass(pageindex=1, and pagesize=5).
so i have added an extra row "show more results" on bottom of results that becomes part of autosuggest list, and when i click on that i want to fetch 5 more items from server from same call and prepend to existing search results keeping the "show more results" item on bottom for next records and so on. 
My problem is here that i was able to prepend results but autocomplete css and behaviour is not being applied to those items which i am appending on select call.

here is my code:

function doneTyping(isSeeMoreReq) {

```
    $(".Handle").autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {

            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                url: '/Admin/GetSearchResult?term='
                    + $('.Handle').val()
                    + "&pageIndex=" + $('#hdnpageIndex').val()
                    + "&pageSize=" + $('#hdnpageSize').val(),
                success: function (data) {
                    //$(".autosuggest-section ul").empty("<li></li>");

                    //if (data != "") {
                    //    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    //        $(".autosuggest-section ul").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
                    //        $(".autosuggest-section").css('display', 'block');
                    //    })
                    //}

                    var array = data.error ? [] : $.map(data, function (m) {
                        return {
                            label: m.EntityHandle,
                            value: m.EntityHandleId,
                            imageid: m.ImageUrl
                        };

                    });
                    if (array.length > 0) {
                        // var objViewMore = array[array.length - 1];
                        var objViewMore = { label: "See More Results", value: -1 };
                        // objViewMore.label = "View More"; objViewMore.value = -1;
                        array.push(objViewMore);
                    }
                    response(array);
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
            event.preventDefault();
            //$(this).autocomplete("search");
            //$(this).autocomplete("enable");

        },
        open: function () {
            $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.element.addClass("custom-autocomplete");
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (ui.item.value == -1) {
                $("#hdnpageIndex").val(parseInt($("#hdnpageIndex").val()) + 1);
                $("#hdnpageSize").val(5);
                // $(".Handle").autocomplete("search", "few");
                //$(this).keydown();
                // $(".Handle").autocomplete("enable");
                // $(".Handle").autocomplete("search").val();
                // $('.Handle').trigger('change');
                // $(".Handle").autocomplete("option", "delay", 200);

                $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/Admin/GetSearchResult?term='
                        + $('.Handle').val()
                        + "&pageIndex=" + $('#hdnpageIndex').val()
                        + "&pageSize=" + $('#hdnpageSize').val(),
                    success: function (data) {

                        var array = data.error ? [] : $.map(data, function (m) {
                            return {
                                label: m.EntityHandle,
                                value: m.EntityHandleId,
                                imageid: m.ImageUrl
                            };

                        });                            
                        $.each(array, function (key, item) {

                            $(".custom-autocomplete").prepend("<li class='ui-menu-item' role='presentation'><a id=ui-id-" + key * 200 + " class='ui-corner-all' tabindex='-1'><div class='program-img'><img src='" + item.imageid + "'/></div><span class='" + item.value + " autosuggest-program-name'></span>" + item.label + "</a></li>");
                        });
                        $(".custom-autocomplete").css("display", "block");
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
            else {
                //$("#linkHandle").val(ui.item.label.replace("<b>", '').replace("</b>", '')); // display the selected text
                var inputText = ui.item.label;
                $("#linkHandle").val(inputText.replace(/<b>/g, ' ').replace(/<\/b>/g, ' ')); // display the selected text
                $("#hdnEntityHandleId").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
                $("#linkHandle").prop('disabled', true);
            }
            // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
            //event.preventDefault();
            // navigate to the selected item's url
            //window.open(ui.item.url);
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
           .data("item.autocomplete", item)
           .append("<a><div class='program-img'><img src='" + item.imageid + "'/></div><span class='" + item.value + " autosuggest-program-name'>" + item.label + "</span></a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
}
```

Comment: Did you fix this? I'm very interested in the solution

Comment: We revamped our project to angular with that it was easy development :).